[2+2]-cycloaddition of trans-cinnamic acid
I was wondering how the 2+2-cycloaddition of trans-cinnamic acid worked in terms of orbitals.

Apparently, this reaction selectively gives this product. In terms of orbitals, the source says that one HOMO (the pi orbital) has to be excited by UV-light, which makes sense, and then it interacts with another LUMO from another molecule: The lobes of the molecules MUST align in this way to get this product:

I can, however, draw the product to get the correct one but in my opinion there should be two correct structures.
The original paper says:

Suprafacial–suprafacial (same algebraic sign at both ends)and antarafacial–antarafacial (opposite algebraic sign at bothends)  orbital  symmetries  are  plausible  orientations  for  cy-cloaddition.  In  this  experiment,  only  the  head-to-tail,suprafacial–suprafacial  product  is  formed  because  theantarafacial–antarafacial product is geometrically impossible.

But is figure B not showing exactly the opposite? In B, the orbital signs are exactly swapped (I guess they are parallel to each other). Why can’t they have the same orientation and then cyclisize?

Argument B is sound. If dry film implies the solid state, the observed regiochemistry may be the result of solid state orientation.

True, the argument itself makes sense, but how do the orbitals need to overlap exactly in this way.. why can't the lobes be oriented with the same sign? The text passage for this is contradictory
